# Laravel Mix, Jquery, Materialize ''$(...).collapsible is not a function"

Tags: jquery, laravel, materialize

i am working on a new laravel mix project with Materialize Css and wanted to import jquery.
Everything worked fine. Everything compiled like it should, i can even find the function in the app.js. But when i want to use the collapsible function it states

> jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).collapsible is not a function TypeError: $(...).collapsible is not a function

My code looks like this

app.blade.php

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Fonts -->
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

<!-- Styles -->
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

`

accordion.blade.php

```
<ul class="collapsible">
    <li class="active">
        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">bookmark_outline</i>Openstaande Werkbonnen</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body">
            <table class="striped responsive-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Naam</th>
                        <th>Start Datum</th>
                        <th>Eind Datum</th>
                        <th>Info</th>
                        <th>Acties</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Werkbon 1</td>
                        <td>29-02-2021</td>
                        <td>29-03-2021</td>
                        <td>Dit is belangrijke informatie</td>
                        <td>
                            <i class="material-icons">
                                <a href="#" class="indigo-text">public</a>
                                <a href="#" class="green-text">check_circle</a>
                                <a href="#" class="orange-text">create</a>
                                <a href="#" class="red-text">delete</a>
                            </i>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons-outlined">bookmark_added</i>Afgeronde Werkbonnen
        </div>
        <div class="collapsible-body">
            <table class="striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Naam</th>
                        <th>Start Datum</th>
                        <th>Eind Datum</th>
                        <th>Info</th>
                        <th>Acties</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Naam</td>
                        <td>Start Datum</td>
                        <td>Eind Datum</td>
                        <td>Informatie</td>
                        <td>
                            <i class="material-icons">w
                                <a class="blue-text">public</a>
                                <a class="red-text">delete</a>
                            </i>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.collapsible').collapsible();
});
```

bootstrap.js

```
window._ = require('material-icons');
window._ = require("materialize-css");
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DA1W6.png

Answer (score 0):

Somehow with just some fiddling it worked with this small fix

Bootstrap.js

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
window._ = require('material-icons');
window._ = require("materialize-css");
```

Just switched jquery to the top and it works now! Weird... but ok :)